# Warning message printed to console not failing the build

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, compiler-warnings, visual-leak-detector

I have warnings as errors turned on and the warning level cranked up to the max. I've integrated [VLD](http://vld.codeplex.com/) in my unit tests. When I purposefully create memory leaks, VLD prints a warning in the Visual Studio output console and the warnings console.

The warning is formatted like `warning : Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!`

However, Visual Studio reports that the build succeeds. **Is warnings as errors limited to Visual Studio generated warnings?**

Comment: You are mixing up building with running.  VLD can only detect leaks when it runs your code.  Which happens *after* you build.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry I didn't make it clear in the question, my unit tests execute as a part of a post-build event. The post build event writes warnings to the console in a format the Visual Studio is able to display in the warnings tab... Basically I just forgot that VS relies on the exit codes of external tools to determine success or not... and that "warnings as errors" affects compile warnings only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the "warnings are errors" is a compiler setting, which basically says "If (error_level == warning) error_level = error;" inside the compiler.

Comment: Could you clarify your answer a bit? Warnings generated by post build events don't fail the build because they don't come from the compiler?

Comment: It's really to do with "exit codes". A warning, normally, gives an exit code of zero from the application. When the compiler is told "treat warnings as errors", it will exit with a non-zero exit code. Visual leak detector would need to also exit with a non-zero exit code to stop the application from failing. I guess you could add a wrapper around the VLD to give a different exit code if there is a warning in the output text...

Comment: Not sure I want to get VLD to change the exit code... I already have UT++ controlling the return codes, I don't want them fighting over it. My current work around was to write the report to a file then have a post build event grep the file for the error and exit with a non-zero code to fail the build. (However, in an upcoming project there is a multithreaded build with all UTs residing in same directory. It will be a bit of work to make sure they all use unique leak report files).

Comment: I should clarify, multiple UT post build processes all in the same working directory and being executed in parallel, so a single leak report file is a no go.

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of solution I was trying to explain, either searching the output, or passing the output through some other tool. So, just use grep in all the leak reports?